# Custom color fails when optional comment argument used with changes.sty command

Tags: changes, trackchanges

I defined a custom color for use with the track-changes package `changes.sty`.  It works well *except* when I add a comment argument to the optional arguments of a command.

Can anyone confirm getting this behaviour and suggest a work-around?

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.1} % Custom colour
\usepackage{changes}
\definechangesauthor[color=magenta]{AA}
\definechangesauthor[color=darkgreen]{BB} % Author BB uses custom colour

\begin{document}

% No comment or custom colour: WORKS FINE
Quick \added[id=AA]{brown} fox jumped.

% Comment but no custom colour: WORKS FINE
Quick \added[id=AA,comment={Not red}]{brown} fox jumped.

% No comment or custom colour: WORKS FINE
Quick \added[id=BB]{brown} fox jumped.

% Comment and custom colour: GENERATES ERROR (Line 19)
Quick \added[id=BB,comment={Not red}]{brown} fox jumped.
   % ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model `'.
   %
   % See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
   % Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
   %  ...
   %
   % l.19 Quick \added[id=BB,comment={Not red}]{brown}
   %                                                   fox jumped.

\end{document}
```

**P.S.** I tried to pretty up the example by giving wide margins for the comment arguments, but `changes.sty` doesn't seem to use those margins. A search of the PDF documention for "width" doesn't turn up anything that I recognize as a parameter for controlling the width of the margin balloons for containing the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes package loads `xcolor` and so colors are processed in the syntax of this package. But you defined your color in the syntax of the `color` package, and this confuses `xcolor`. Either load xcolor instead of color or move your definition behind the `changes` package:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\usepackage{changes}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.1} % Custom colour
\definechangesauthor[color=magenta]{AA}
\definechangesauthor[color=darkgreen]{BB} % Author BB uses custom colour

\begin{document}

% No comment or custom colour: WORKS FINE
Quick \added[id=AA]{brown} fox jumped.

% Comment but no custom colour: WORKS FINE
Quick \added[id=AA,comment={Not red}]{brown} fox jumped.

% No comment or custom colour: WORKS FINE
Quick \added[id=BB]{brown} fox jumped.

Quick \added[id=BB,comment={Not red}]{brown} fox jumped.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike.  That works perfectly.  And Googling the difference between `color` and `xcolor` packages was educational in that there are many packages with x-prefix counterparts. On a separate note, would you be able to comment on the closing paragraph of my originally posted question?  Should I spin that out to its own question?